# Buddypress: ask and display specific member data related to a group

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I would like to store specific data of my users depending in the group.

For example:
In the group “NY Marathon” the number of participation of member 1 will be 195.
In the group “Boston Matahon” the number for member 1 will be 345.

Any idea to do something like that? Are xProfiles designed for that?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use user meta for storing this information. Here is an example of how you'd update user meta using `update_user_meta`:

```
$user_id = 1;
$key = 'ny_marathon';
$value = '195';
update_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $value );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta

To get that stored data at a later date and display it on your page you would use `get_user_meta`:

```
$user_id = 1;
$key = 'ny_marathon';
$participator_number = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, true );
echo 'Runner number' . $participator_number;
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answer,

I wish I had seen it before. But finally, I think I've done a more complete workaround.

I have created a xprofile_field called "participation_number". Then, every time a user registers its participation number for a race:

- it check if a child field with name equals to id of the race group exists
- if not it adds this child
- it adds a new xprofile_field_value with the number of participation for this child field

The nice thing is that it allows to relate the new info directly to the id of the group, and makes also possible to create other fields in order to ask other types of information for a particular group.

If anyone interested to know more, feel free to ask :)